# Theory of General relativity — not renormalizable

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, renormalization

I have a short question: what does it mean when one says that General relativity is not renormalizable?

I guess unlike the Quantum Field Theory, but what is the idea behind this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we say that GR is non-renormalizable, we generally mean that the tools we used in other field theories to get rid of infinities are not working in this case. For example if we treat gravity as a quantum field theory, we can expand around flat spacetime.
$$
g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}
$$

If we perturb around the field $h_{\mu\nu}$, the action becomes$$
\mathcal{S}_{gravity}\sim \frac{1}{16\pi G}\int{d^4x} \;(\partial h)^2(1+h^2+...)
$$
$$
\sim\int{d^4x}(dh)^2\left[{\frac{1}{16\pi G}}+\left({\frac{1}{16\pi G}}\right)^2h^2+..\right]
$$

Now, the couplings of each $(1+h^2+..)$ will have higher and higher powers. The couplings in the action (namely the terms which contain the gravitational constant $G$) have mass dimension -2. This means our couplings have mass dimensions $[\lambda] < 0$. In general for a theory to be renormalizable we need $[\lambda] \ge 0$. In other words, there are more divergencies in our theory than there are counter-terms.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Just a little detail : 

you do a Taylor development, right ? How do you  get :

$\left(\dfrac{1}{16\pi G}\right)^{2}$

into

$$\sim\int{d^4x}(dh)^2\left[{\frac{1}{16\pi G}}+\left({\frac{1}{16\pi G}}\right)^2h^2+..\right]$$

Comment: (from the asker, not from me)

Comment: @redhood : just a reminder if you have the time : how do you make appear the terms  $\left(\dfrac{1}{16\pi G}\right)^{2}$ and others superior orders ? Regards

Comment: We expand $\sqrt{-g}$ which is a power series in $h$ and then by dimensional analysis we have increasing powers of $\frac{1}{16\pi G}$. If you are wondering how to expand $\sqrt{-g}$ check this question(https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/how-do-i-calculate-the-perturbations-to-the-metric-determinant)