# Understanding in perturbation of metric in tensor calculus

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, perturbation-theory, linear-algebra, trace

From the post [demonstration of expand perturbations of metric](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3873/how-do-i-calculate-the-perturbations-to-the-metric-determinant),

I understand the full demo below excepted for the last result, i.e :

$$
\sqrt{-g}=\sqrt{-\operatorname{det} b}\left(1+\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}\left(b^{-1} h\right)-\frac{1}{4} \operatorname{tr}\left(b^{-1} h\right)^{2}+\frac{1}{8} \operatorname{tr}^{2}\left(b^{-1} h\right)\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(h^{3}\right)
$$
In physics notation this reads
$$
\sqrt{-g}=\sqrt{-b}\left(1+\frac{1}{2} h_{\mu}^{\mu}-\frac{1}{4} h^{\mu \nu} h_{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{8}\left(h_{\mu}^{\mu}\right)^{2}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(h^{3}\right)
$$

I have problems of understand to derive for example  $$\frac{1}{2} h_{\mu}^{\mu}\equiv \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}\left(b^{-1} h\right)$$

Here the full demo :

\begin{align}
\sqrt{-\det{g}} = \sqrt{-\det{(b+h)}} &= \exp\log\sqrt{-\det{(b+h)}}\\
&= \exp{\frac{1}{2}\log{(-\det{(b+h)})}}\\
&= \exp{\frac{1}{2}\log{(-\det{b}\det{(1+b^{-1}h)})}}\\
&= \exp{\left[\log{\sqrt{-\det{b}}} + \frac{1}{2}\log{\det{(1+b^{-1}h)}}\right]}\\
&= \sqrt{-\det{b}}\exp{\left[\frac{1}{2}\log{\det{(1+b^{-1}h)}}\right]}\\
&= \sqrt{-\det{b}}\exp{\left[\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}{\log{(1+b^{-1}h)}}\right]}\\
&= \sqrt{-\det{b}}\exp{\left[\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}{\left[b^{-1}h-\frac{1}{2}(b^{-1}h)^2+\dots\right]}\right]}\\
&= \sqrt{-\det{b}}\exp{\left[\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(b^{-1}h)-\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{tr}{(b^{-1}h)^2}+\dots\right]}\\
&= \sqrt{-\det{b}}\left(1 + \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(b^{-1}h)-\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{tr}{(b^{-1}h)^2} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(b^{-1}h)-\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{tr}{(b^{-1}h)^2}\right)^2\right) + \mathcal O(h^3)\\
&= \sqrt{-\det{b}}\left(1 + \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{tr}(b^{-1}h)-\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{tr}{(b^{-1}h)^2} + \frac{1}{8}\operatorname{tr}^2{(b^{-1}h)}\right) + \mathcal O(h^3)\\
\end{align}

In physics notation this reads
$$
\sqrt{-g}=\sqrt{-b}\left(1+\frac{1}{2} h_{\mu}^{\mu}-\frac{1}{4} h^{\mu \nu} h_{\mu \nu}+\frac{1}{8}\left(h_{\mu}^{\mu}\right)^{2}\right)+\mathcal{O}\left(h^{3}\right)
$$

How to make match these 2 terms : $\frac{1}{2} h_{\mu}^{\mu}$ and $\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{tr}\left(b^{-1} h\right)$ ?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$b$ is their notation for the  original metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and
$b^{-1}$ is just their notation for the inverse metric $g^{\mu\nu}$. So  ${\rm tr} \{b^{-1}h\}=g^{\mu\alpha} h_{\alpha \mu}={h^\mu}_\mu$, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However, in the answer of the post cited, they have written : $$g_{\mu \nu}=b_{\mu \nu}+h_{\mu \nu}$$ , so $b_{\mu\nu}$ can't be equal to $g_{\mu\nu}$, can it be ?

Comment: Just  notation. The *standard* notation is  $g_{\mu\nu}\to g_{\mu\nu}+ h_{\mu\nu}$. I used the standard notation because who ever used the "b"notation was just being difficult.

Comment: Okay, I understand better this way. thanks